# How can I toggle a radio button's checked state with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

As can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/jy6t5oru/), I've got this HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="radbtnEmp" >rad btn</input>
```

...and this jQuery:

```
$('#radbtnEmp').click(function () {
    alert("radbtnEmp clicked");
});
```

The alert *does* display when I click the radio button; However, clicking the radio button a second time does not toggle its state back to unchecked. How can I do that in jQuery?

I want to be able to respond to its state like this (or something similar):

```
if ($('#radbtnEmp').attr('checked', true)) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

...but if the radiobutton is never checked/false, that doesn't work.

Comment: Radio buttons can't be toggled back to "unchecked", that's not how they work, you should use a checkbox for that.

Comment: Are you after this? -> [http://jsfiddle.net/jy6t5oru/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/jy6t5oru/1/)?

Comment: FYI, inputs are void elements, it cannot contains any other element, there is no closing tag

Comment: @A.Wolff. Do you mean it's supposed to look like this:
<input type="radio" id="radbtnEmp">rad btn
That looks bizarre to me...

Comment: Yes, exactly like that, some elements are self-closing and don't have closing tags and can't contain text or children elements.

Comment: @LShetty: That's close - got me going down the right path. I ended up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/jy6t5oru/3/

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I think basically you want: `<label><input type="checkbox" id="ckbxEmp">czech Bachs</label>` to make the relevant checkbox text clickable. If i'm right, in XHTML, you should self close input element: `<input type="checkbox" id="ckbxEmp" />`

Comment: @A.Wolff: I don't need the *text* to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the radio buttons cannot be checked and unchecked..

For that you need to use checkboxes:

Html:

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "myCheckBox">I am CheckBox</input>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myCheckBox').on('click', function() {

    if ($('#myCheckBox').is(':checked')) {
        // code
    }
    else {
        // code
    }
})
```

Hope this helps